# What API access is required for this job posting app?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to build a simple LinkedIn app that shares a selection of our job postings to our LinkedIn company feed. The job postings are pages on our website, not LinkedIn Jobs. Is the Community Management API access required for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

The first version of the question was about posting jobs to LinkedIn.

You will need the "Job Postings API", under the Talent Section.

Some caveats and links to see, in least to most technical detail:

- An ATS, or Applicant Tracking System, is a system aimed at automating job postings and screening candidates.   They often handling putting your job on LinkedIn.  [Here](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/talent-acquisition/pages/ats-table.aspx) is a whole list of them.
- You may find that for jobs that are not promoted, aka Basic Jobs, you can just pass over an XML feed.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/job-postings/xml-feeds).
- The Job Posting Overview is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/job-postings/job-posting-overview#frequently-asked-questions).
- The slightly more technical overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/job-postings/api/overview).
- A more technical blog post is [here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2022/linkedin-s-simple--unified--and-discoverable-job-postings-api-).
- A more technical sample using the API is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/job-postings/api/create-jobs)

This is theortical on my side; I have never used this particular API.

Good luck in your coding adventures!

Answer (score 0):

Answering the different question, "I want to provide updates to our Company's LinkedIn page to link to our own pages"

- You can just add your new offerings as a feed, using ["Share on Linked In"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin)
- You can also use the [Share Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) to streamline this.

Otherwise,I'm unclear what you are tyring to do.  I recommend just playing with the feed APIs first:  they are easy and require little approval.  Once you apply to a more specific API, you may trip over the terms of service.   Community Manager APIs are unlikely to be helpful to you:  they are primarily aimed at following those that mention your company in other contexts.

Answer (score -4):

Here are the key steps and considerations regarding the required API access:

1. **LinkedIn Developer Account:** Ensure that you have a LinkedIn Developer account, as you will need it to create and manage your app.
2. **App Creation:** Create a new app in the LinkedIn Developer portal. This app will be used to obtain the necessary API credentials and manage your integration.
3. **API Selection:** When creating your app, select the "Share on LinkedIn" or "Share API" if available. These APIs are designed for sharing content, including job postings, on LinkedIn.
4. **Permissions:** Check the permissions required for the selected API. You will likely need permissions related to posting updates on behalf of your company page.
5. **Apply for Access:** If the API you selected requires specific permissions or access, apply for access through the LinkedIn Developer portal. Follow the provided instructions for requesting access.
6. **Authentication:** Implement OAuth 2.0 authentication to securely connect your app to your LinkedIn account and obtain the necessary access tokens.
7. **Integration:** Develop your app to programmatically create and share updates on your LinkedIn company feed. You will use the API endpoints and libraries provided by LinkedIn to achieve this functionality.
8. **Testing and Compliance:** Thoroughly test your app to ensure that it correctly shares job postings on your company's LinkedIn feed. Make sure your app complies with LinkedIn's API usage policies and rate limits.
9. **Deployment and Monitoring:** After successful testing, deploy your app and continue to monitor its behavior to ensure it operates reliably and remains compliant with LinkedIn's policies.